# Assume $m$ divides $n$. Show for any integer $a$, $[a]_m$ is the union of $[a]_n, [a+m]_n, [a+2m]_n,..., [a+(n-m)]_n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences, equivalence-relations

Exercise 6 from Section 1.4 of Beachy, Blair: *Abstract Algebra*, 2006.

> Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that $m\mid n$. Show that for any integer $a$, the congruence class $[a]_m$ is the union of the congruence classes $[a]_n, [a+m]_n, [a+2m]_n, \dots, [a+n-m]_n$.

This is an exercise from Abstract Algebra by Beachy and Blair involving congruence classes. I understand that the congruence classes are sets, and I'm assuming the best approach would be to explore the meaning of that union of congruence classes and hopefully realize it equals $[a]_m$. other than that I can't find my bearings at all. I'm not sure what this really means. any hints/advice appreciated, I am not asking for the answer.

Comment: you could at least tell me how to reword this to meet your next to impossible standards, I literally just want help, I'm tired of your games

Comment: One simple improvement is to use latex. Someone just did that for you. Also, some users voted to close your question as unclear. This is understandable since, in the first edition of this question, you did not define what is [a+m]n (And it took me some times to realize what you are referring to).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$[a]_m= \{a+lm:l\in \mathbb Z\}$,  whereas $[a+km]_n=\{a+km+ldm:  l\in \mathbb Z\}$, where $d=\frac nm$ ...

In the latter case you can see that you sort of have an $m$ equivalence class (with some missing elements...) 
The missing elements get filled in when $k$ ranges from $0$ to $d-1$...

You may want to look at some concrete examples...  For instance $m=2$ and $n=8$...
Then, say $a=1$.
$[1]_2=\{1+2l: l\in \mathbb Z\}$, whereas 
$[1]_8=\{1+8l: l\in \mathbb Z\}$,
$[1+2]_8=[3]_8=\{3+8l:l\in \mathbb Z\}$,
$[1+4]_8=[5]_8=\{5+8l:l\in  \mathbb Z\}$ and
$[1+6]_8=[7]_8=\{7+8l: l\in \mathbb Z\}$...

The union of the last four sets equals the first (namely the odd integers)...

The key is that modding out by $n$ is less precise (than by $m$):  we need to account for the equivalence classes at increments of $m$ to make up for that...

Comment: 1. No, $[a]_m$ is not $\{a, a+m, a+2m,\dots\}$ (a statement that the rest of your post contradicts anyway, for example when you state (correctly) that $[1]_2=\{\dots, -3,-1,1,3,5,7,9, \dots\}$ instead of $[1]_2=\{1,3,5,7,9, \dots\}$). 2. Why all the ellipses? These can be avoided, for example $[a]_m=\{a+km\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$, leading to a more readable proof and naturally suggesting some powerful mathematical arguments simplifying the proof.

Comment: @Did thanks for the correction and advice.   I have edited.